# Show that if A is diagonalizable, then sin^2(A) + cos^2(A) = I. Does this identity also hold for nondiagonalizable matrices?

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing, diagonalization

Show that if A is diagonalizable, then $\sin^2(A)+\cos^2(A)=I$. Does this identity also hold for nondiagonalizable matrices?
This is what I got so far:
$$
e^{iA}= \cos A +i\sin A \\
    \cos A= \frac{e^{iA}+e^{-iA}}{2} \\
\sin A= \frac{ie^{-iA}-ie^{iA}}{2} \\
\cos^2(A) + \sin^2(A)= I
$$
What should I write to complete this proof? How do I show that this identity hold in general(i.e nondiagonalizable matrices) ? Please help

Comment: Let $A=P^{-1}DP$ be a diagonalisation. Can you show that $\exp(A)=P^{-1}\exp(D)P$? Because that is a big step on the way.

Comment: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: What are your exact definitions of $\sin(A)$ and $\cos(A)$? One approach is just to compute everything using Cauchy-products and use that this gives the same formal expression as if $A$ was a real/complex number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are essentially there (and without using diagonalisability), provided you know the expressions for $\cos A$ and $\sin A$ are indeed generally valid for square matrices $A$ (for instance they might be the definitions). I would avoid writing down the conclusion immediately, as it may raise the suspicion that you did so without having an argument. To show you do, just write
$$
  \cos(A)^2=\frac{e^{2iA}+2I+e^{-2iA}}4
\quad\text{and}\quad
  \sin(A)^2=\frac{i^2e^{-2iA}-2i^2I+(-i)^2e^{2iA}}4
$$
so that $\cos(A)^2+\sin(A)^2=\frac{2I--2I}4=I$.